# Not able to connect to a slave machine in JMeter distributed testing [JMeter Distributed Testing]

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, distributed-testing

I am trying to setup a master-slave environment to perform distributed testing in JMeter, But even after setting up all the things, i am unable to do so.

Below configurations i already setup:

1. Firewall is disable.
2. RMI keystore is generated from master machine and the created "jks" file has been pasted to all slave machine. Also for alternative solution, i marked "server.rmi.ssl.disable" as "true" in "user.properties" fike.
3. I also setup a server port in "jmeter.properties" file with slave ip addresses as well.

[image]

but after doing all the above listed things, i am getting error as "Connection timed out" and "Connection Refused to host".

can anyone please help me to overcome the problem ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to each slave machine `jmeter-server` file and then start `jmeter-server` from slave machines:

```
RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname= ip_of_your_jmeter_server
```

Comment: Thank you Masud for the answer. but still i am unable to connect to slave machines.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blindly changing JMeter properties values (and doing this in [wrong files](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)) I would rather recommend getting familiarized with  [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) section of JMeter documentation and pay particular attention to the following:

- `client.rmi.localport` - Parameter that controls the RMI ports used by RemoteSampleListenerImpl and RemoteThreadsListenerImpl (The Controller)
- `server.rmi.port` - To change the default port (1099) used to access the server.
- `server.rmi.localport` - To use a specific port for the JMeter server engine, define this property before starting the server.
- `server_port` - RMI port to be used by the server (must start rmiregistry with same port).

Where:

- `client` (or `Controller`) == JMeter Master
- `server` == JMeter Slave

More information:

- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

---

We cannot suggest any fixes without seeing what properties you've defined on master and slave machines, for now I can mention that:

1. If you want to change `server_port` from default `1099` to `1234` you need to do this **on the slaves side**
2. On the master side you need to make JMeter aware of the port change via `remote_hosts` property like

   ```
   remote_hosts=1.1.1.1:1234,2.2.2.2:1234,etc.
   ```

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for the4 answer. I tried all your mentioned solutions but still i am unable to connect to slave machines.